# Unable to ssh on to an Ubuntu VM hosted in Hyper V on Windows 11

Tags: fedora, windows, hyper-v

As the title says, I'm trying to access a Linux vm, running in Hyper V on Windows 11 host, from a Fedora machine connected to the same network like the Windows 11 host. I have created a NAT network for the Hyper V VMs, and can ssh from the Windows host on the Linux VM. I have also enabled ip forwarding and routing on the Windows 11 host, amd created a rule for the 22 port.

On the Linux machine I have created a new route to ip 172.28.80.0/24 going through the ip of the Windows host. Even with all these settings, the ssh connection to the Linux VM is not working.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The fact that I'm using NAT for my machines is the issue.

The `SYN` from my Linux machine reaches the VM, but the `SYN,ACK` has the Windows host's IP address as the source and is, thus, dropped by the kernel of my Linux machine.